# Regina Extra Freewheel or Cassette

Tags: gears, cassette, freewheel

I have a road bike (Carlton Flyer, 1977) with a regina extra rear cassette. I'm interested in downgearing it (i live on a massive hill) and am trying to identify whether it is a freewheel or cassette and if downgearing is possible - before I start pulling it apart.

Pic [image: regina extra]

Ideally, I'd like to replace it with the same type, or add an extra ring at the top to give me a climbing gear. Doesn't have indexed shifters so I don't think that would be an issue.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, that age would be a fairly generic freewheel.

Comment: You could change the chainrings for smaller ones, two or even one tooth less would make a great change in gearing.

Comment: Looks like a six speed freewheel  with a 13 tooth small and a 21 tooth large.    I can see no lock ring which suggests a freewheel.  There's not much wear evident, so you might go for a 6 speed 12-25 which leaves you with larger gaps.  What's your riding style like - do you want more at the top or the bottom end of the gear range ?

Answer (score 3):

It is a freewheel. You will need the appropriate freewheel tool. The tool typically won't fit without removing the axle. You may also need the correct cone wrenches. This makes it a good time to service the wheels bearings as well. You may want to consult your LBS and compare the cost of having it done versus purchasing the tools you may only use once.

Answer (score 0):

You need Med to long dérailleur for 32t+34t Cogs. Not sure but, yours should be long, due to age. You can't add a gear. Road bikes usually do not have a 32t cog. Change out your large cog for a 32t cog. You may need a longer chain too. Here is a link on freewheels customizing etc...http://www.sheldonbrown.com/freewheels.html